# Wordpress Post Featured Image Dynanic Resizing

Tags: php, image, wordpress

I have a theme where I have different type of templates for different categories . Since thumbnail size is set to a fixed one . Images on different categories are not showin properly  . Is there any way to have image size dynamic for categories/templates instead of whole system ? I can have same post in multiple categories which creates problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define different sizes for each category.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size